# Do Apple stores refuse to repair your iPhone if not purchased directly from Apple?

Tags: iphone, warranty, applecare

I am planning to buy an iPhone 6 from an online store. But I have been told that if I buy from anywhere except the Apple store, I won't be able to enjoy the benefits of the warranty and guarantee. Is that true?

Comment: Apple publishes their warranty at http://apple.com/legal - there is no guarantee. Could you edit this to explain more about your doubts? Did some random child on the street tell you this or is there some basis for your uncertainty about what Apple provides? (basically, you are asking a yes/no question so you will basically get one yes answer, one no answer, and lots of opinion and possibly un-needed guesswork)

Answer (score 1):

You can research Apple's warranty at http://apple.com/legal

You will have consumer law protections if you can prove you purchased product in a certain place. Those trump any warranty.

Apple's warranty is attached to the phone (or any serialized product), so all that matters is what country that serial number was first sold as Apple's records show. They then warrant that one device under that one legal framework.

The warranty doesn't need proof of purchase, but most of the agreements I've read say "Apple or its agents may require that you furnish proof of purchase details" which protects them against stolen or counterfeit serial numbers if there is doubt.

I would recommend you get a written invoice with the business name and the serial number of the iPhone so you are covered in case Apple exercises the "may require" clause, but I've never heard of anyone actually reporting that they needed to provide proof of purchase as Apple typically honors their warranty to the letter and often treats consumers better than the warranty allows.

Comment: Unless you live in Europe. My phone is out of the one year Apple warranty, but within the 2 year warranty period we have in Europe called consumer warranty. For this case, Apple asked me for the purchase proof. Doesn't make sense because they have it in their system when and where the device was bought, but they are still requesting it. If you are inside the 2 year consumer warranty but lost your purchase proof, too bad for you :(

Comment: @Dante I've heard that is the legal framework in Europe from others as well. The responsibility to do certain things shifts from the vendor (often the specific shop where the sale occurred) to the manufacturer and to the end user over time. Hopefully, the store you purchased it has records - I've generally had good luck getting a duplicate from Apple when I have the serial number and approximate date/location of the sale.

Answer (score 0):

Apple will honor the warranty of any device sold from an authorized dealer. If you buy a second hand device from an individual I **believe** the original warranty is in effect from the *original sale date.* EG the warranty starts from the time Apple or the authorized dealer sold it to the person you bought it from.

Your best bet might be to ask someone at an Apple store for a definitive, authoritative answer. Either that or call Apple support.

Comment: Additionally if the device was purchased with AppleCare (and properly enrolled), then the extended warrantee is transferred to the new owner.

Comment: I've never known Apple to care how you acquired product. All serialized products are sold through a channel that establishes which legal entity backs the warranty. I'll provide an answer if that's really what the OP is asking. The warranty is attached to the device, not some reseller or even a person/company so all that matters is what Apple's records say for that product in terms of country of first sale.