# Will AppleCare+ repair a device not originally purchased by me?

Tags: iphone, repair, apple-store, warranty, applecare

I purchased an iPhone SE 3rd generation on Back Market, an online store for second-hand electronics. The device comes with a valid AppleCare+ warranty. Can I use it to repair this device at an Apple Store, even though it was originally purchased by someone else I don’t personally know?

[image]

There is a [related question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/187981/do-apple-stores-refuse-to-repair-your-iphone-if-not-purchased-directly-from-appl), but this one is not a duplicate of it because I’m asking about second hand devices instead of new devices coming from authorized resellers.

Comment: I bought an iMac second hand - Apple repaired it under their warranty program, no issues...

Answer (score 1):

They usually don't check and will probably repair anyway but in the future you should [transfer AppleCare ownership](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202712)

1. [Sign in to My Support](https://support.apple.com/my-support) to get the AppleCare agreement number, the serial number of the device, and the proof of coverage for the AppleCare plan.
2. Find the original sales receipt for the device.
3. Get the new owner’s name, address, email address, and phone number.
4. [Contact Apple Support](https://getsupport.apple.com/?caller=kbase&PGF=PGF66001&category_id=SC0089&symptom_id=20455).